# Is it possible repeating same Radio button with different check value?

Tags: php, html, radio-button

My question is regarding radio buttons. I have 10 radio buttons with the same name and sequential values. One of the radio buttons is checked. Sample code mentioned below:

```
<li><input type="radio" value="1000" checked="checked" name="status" />Yet to contact</li>
<li><input type="radio" value="1001" name="status"/>To call back, follow up</li>
<li><input type="radio" value="1002" name="status"/>Interested, to meet</li>
<li><input type="radio" value="1003" name="status"/>Meeting over, to follow up</li>
<li><input type="radio" value="1004" name="status"/>Meeting over, not interested</li>
<li><input type="radio" value="1005" name="status"/>Not interested now</li>
<li><input type="radio" value="1006" name="status"/>Wrong contact details</li>
<li><input type="radio" value="1007" name="status"/>Services taken</li>
```

Above code will be a dynamic code through PHP and will repeat many times on single page. However, I have tried in plain html code and found that it creates a problem and does not show any radio button selected. If I group it by different name like name="status[1]" and name="status[2]" then only every group of radio button show a checked radio button.

Does anyone have a solution where I can keep the same name for all radio buttons and each group (with same name) of radio buttons will show me a default radio button selected?

Comment: Did you try to put them in fieldsets?

Comment: Well I've checked your code in W3Schools as I couldn't see anything wrong and it works fine.  So not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Hi RedEyeMonster, Thank for your reply. Please repeat same code two to three times on same page. You will find a problem.

Comment: If you give all radio menus the same name, then how will the browser tell them apart? Radio buttons are designed so that each menu (each set of radio buttons) can only have a single option selected. When one gets selected, all the rest get deselected. If you want to create different radio menus, but you give them all the same name (and put them all in the same form), then to the browser it just looks like one single big radio menu.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly:

Specify an array in the `name` attribute of your radio button.

```
<input  type="radio" name="check[]" value="1" />
<input  type="radio" name="check[]" value="2" />
<input  type="radio" name="check[]" value="3" />
```

When you use `$_POST['check']` you'll get an array containing index and value of radio buttons checked.

Suppose if you checked 1st and 3rd radio button, the array would be like:

`array('0'=>'1', '2'=>'3')`

Comment: Hi Asprin you are somehow half right. However, i am going to repeat same radio button with same name as array and value again but while repeating default radio button checked value would be different. I hope you will understand what i want explain it to you..

Comment: That's incorrect. Firstly, the `foo[]` format of specifying array data is a PHP idiosyncrasy not an HTTP standard. In all other languages, the way you do it is by simply giving all the inputs the same name (e.g. `?foo=val1&foo=val2&foo=val3`). Secondly, radio buttons return a single scalar value, not an array. So even for a PHP backend, you wouldn't need `[]` after the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

The name for each group of radiobuttons has te be unique.

Try something like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
   echo '<li><input type="radio" value="1000" checked="checked" name="status'.$i.'" />Yet to contact</li>
         <li><input type="radio" value="1001" name="status'.$i.'"/>To call back, follow up</li>

         <li><input type="radio" value="1002" name="status'.$i.'"/>Interested, to meet</li>

         <li><input type="radio" value="1003" name="status'.$i.'"/>Meeting over, to follow up</li>

         <li><input type="radio" value="1004" name="status'.$i.'"/>Meeting over, not interested</li>

         <li><input type="radio" value="1005" name="status'.$i.'"/>Not interested now</li>

         <li><input type="radio" value="1006" name="status'.$i.'"/>Wrong contact details</li>

         <li><input type="radio" value="1007" name="status'.$i.'"/>Services taken</li>';
}
```

To read the selected value use:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
   echo $_POST["status$i"] . '<br>;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bram, Your solution is good which i have thought earlier in same way. But how would i catch value of radio button on form submission as each radio button group name is different. Did you thought about this problem? Any solution on this.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. You are calling same array each time and array will count same number as a part of name along with "status" text. I hope i am right and guessing correctly. So if i repeat this code 5 times then every time i will get first radio button with name="status1" and so on. So it mean repeated group of radio button will have same name every time. Please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you fully understand. As you can see in my code I'm using a `for loop`. This loop wil create 5 arrays. The next loop is used to read the 5 arrays after you post your form.

So, you don't have to repeat the code because the loop takes care of that.